# OpenCV Raspberry Pi printf() not displaying

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am trying to make image processing using OpenCV on a Raspberry pi. I've installed the relevant packages and OpenCV but for some reason I cannot manage to compile not even a `printf();`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
printf("hello world");
return 0;
}
```

After I run this using g++ filename.cpp , the output on the console is empty, it does not print anything but asks for the next command.
Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: `g++ filename.cpp` just compiles the program and generates the executable file `a.out`. To execute it, type: `./a.out`

Comment: Thank you! I managed to do it in the end. I am trying to compile and run some samples from opencv/cpp. When I run the program using g++ facedetect.cpp for example, I have some errors: undefined referance to 'cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture()'. What can I do now?

Answer (score 1):

In order to successfully compile your OpenCV project you'll have to link against OpenCV libraries.

When compiling on the command-line I'm always using [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/) to link against needed libraries.

With pkg-config installed, try:

```
g++ `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` -std=c++11 yourfile.cpp
```